# Why does explode return whole array?

Tags: php, php-7

This code returns whole array instead false or NULL, because there are not matches by mask `;`

```
$a = " 6 . 2 . 828194 . 2 . 3 .";

var_dump(explode(';', $a));
```

How to solve this feature?

Result is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(25) " 6 . 2 . 828194 . 2 . 3 ." }
```

Comment: _"If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE. If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, then an empty array will be returned, **otherwise an array containing string will be returned**."_ as it says on the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: I know, but how fix this issue? When there are no matches, how to check? reg expression?

Comment: Do you think it is good behaviour? When it returns otherwise an array containing string will be returned, whereas it should be empty array: []

Comment: It is not an issue, but if you want to check if the string has a specific character, just use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)

Comment: I need array as explode works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just test if the delimiter is there before exploding and do what you want if it's not there.

```
$a = " 6 . 2 . 828194 . 2 . 3 .";
$delim = ";";

if(strpos($a, $delim) !== false){
    var_dump(explode($delim, $a));
}else{
    echo "null";
    // Or
    // $a[] = Null;
}
```

Result: `null`

Comment: It does not work for: `$a = " 6 . 2 . 828194 ; 2 . 3 .";`

Comment: My bad. I swapped the arguments of strpos. https://3v4l.org/6j85K . it's quite annoying that there is no standard for the arguments in php. Sometimes it's the subject first and sometimes it's second or third. You would think all 'similar' functions would be the same.